# LuaLaTex, TeXstudio, biber - Do not compile bibliography when using Compile command

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, luatex, compiling, texstudio

I'm trying to compile a document including a glossary and a bibliography.

For adjustment purposes, I need to compile it every few lines I write. For this I use the TeXstudio command "Compile" (F6 in Windows, `txs:///lualatex` command).

This tends to take a lot of time since every time I use this command, instead of simply calling LuaLaTeX once, it follows the following procedure :

1. `lualatex document`
2. `biber document`
3. `lualatex document`
4. `lualatex document`

I then manually call the Glossary command (F9 or `txs:///makeglossaries`), which does its job, then Compile again (which follows the same procedure as above).

So a total of 6 compiles instead of 2. I would like to disable the call to bibtex when using Compile, but as it does not appear in my Build commands, I'm lost.

Can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance !

[image: My TeXstudio configuration]

Comment: In the middle there is an option "verifier et mettre a jour la bibliographie". There is also an option to change the number of compilations.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer of course ! Thanks, I'll add your comment as an answer.

Comment: You may want to look into [`latexmk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk). `latexmk` is a Perl program that tries to run all necessary tools on your file, but only if that is actually necessary.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, I had actually read about `latexmk` but I currently don't the time or motivation to learn a new tool. But writing Make files and using this are on my mid-term goals list !

Comment: If you can get `latexmk` running it is very easy to use (but you need a Perl installation to run it, which might be a bit of a hassle on Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on @UlrikeFischer 's response, simply going into Options > Configure TeXstudio > Production and de-activating `Check and update bibliography` did the trick for me.

[image]